# Rust borrow checker prevent me to return a reference from iterator

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'd like to know if this is expected behavior.

I'm trying to check value inside Vec before putting a new value into it.
Regardless of whether it's success or not, I'd like to return a reference to that value.

If value already exist, I won't add that value to Vec.

The code below and in playground is a minimal reproduction code.
The value in my real use case isn't implement Copy. So my code below use some simple struct which doesn't implement Copy too.

```rust
use std::iter::Iterator;

struct A (usize);

fn nll_test(v: &mut Vec<A>, value: usize) -> &A {
    if let Some(matched) = v.iter().find(|elm| {elm.0 == value}) {
        return matched
    } else {
        v.push(A(value));
        return &v[v.len() - 1]
    }
}

fn main() {
    const MAX: usize = 100;
    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(MAX);
    nll_test(&mut v, 1);
}
```

When compile, it return following error:

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*v` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

The workaround I found so far is to replace above `nll_test` function with this:

```rust
fn nll_without_iter(v: &mut Vec<A>, value: usize) -> &A {
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        if v[i].0 == value {
            return &v[i]
        }
    }
    
    v.push(A(value));
    &v[v.len() - 1]
}
```

[link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=15f9d255afaec58e6c584196c583fe76)

Comment: I think this is a known [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54663) of the Rust borrow checker. FWIW, your code with `-Z polonius` does compile.